# Jacobian matrix for ellipsoid

Tags: polar-coordinates, volume

ive been asked to fine the jacobian matrix for an ellipsoid $$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2 / c^2 = 1$$

ive been looking online for the parametric equations and i get two different answers

$$x=a\cos(u)\sin(v)\\            
y=b\sin(u)\sin(v)\\ 
z=c\cos(v)$$

or

$$x=r\cos(u)\sin(v)\\
y=r\sin(u)\sin(v)\\
z=r\cos(v)$$
which is right?

i know the jacobian should equal $abc$. but these things have confused me. any help?

Comment: Neither... They just don't fit the original equation.

Comment: Also, since you are looking for the solid ellipsoid parametrisation, I think you have missed the "radius" dimension: your equations are 2-D, even if they were correct they could only describe a surface rather than a solid ellipsoid.

Comment: could you explain that further please?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite know what your "Jacobian" is. But if you are looking for a parametrisation equation, then

1). Parametrisation is not unique. For the same object it's very likely that you have many different ones, each depending on the way you view it.

2). For the ellipsoid $(x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2\le 1)$, a common parametrisation is
$$x=at\sin\theta\cos\phi, y=bt\sin\theta\sin\phi,z=ct\cos\theta,t\in[0,1],\theta\in[0,\pi],\phi\in[0,2\pi]. $$
If you are looking for a parametrisation for the elliptic surface, just let $t=1$ be fixed.